# how to parse text file without delimeters in python

Tags: python

I Need Help with the below file;
Here is the myrecord with sampleline (no delimiters)

`AD03A010125UNITADREESSUPTO25LENGTH0215ADDRESS2WITH15RECORDLENTh0310WANCHAI`

in the above record AD03A01 is common

`01`---Field Tag

`25`--Field Length

`UNITADDRESSUPTO25LENGTH`-----ADDRESSLINE 1 with Record Length of 25

`02`----Field Tag

`15`--Field Length

RECORDLENGTH---------ADDRESS LINE2 with length 15

`03`---Field Tag

`10`--Fields Length

`WANCHAI`---CITY NAME with length 10

so I need it to output like below:

`ADDRESSLINE1,ADDRESSLINE2,CITY`

Comment: Please format your question correctly. This is unreadable.

Comment: Please format your question. As it stands, it's incomprehensible.

Comment: Please use code formatting when adding code into a question or response for easy readability; code formatting uses monospace fonts, as well as highlighting to clearly indicate specified text is code.

Comment: Question is ambiguous, please add your code, format properly

Comment: Please use proper formatting, adding line breaks help somewhat, but please, if you want answers, format properly! Please use code formatting!

Comment: Do the field lengths change? Or are they always 25/15/10

Comment: If field length is for example 25 then what does it really means? Is it 25 chars long or it is **up to 25** chars long?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this, reading the line in chunks

```
from itertools import islice

s = 'AD03A010125UNITADREESSUPTO25LENGTH0215ADDRESS2WITH15RECORDLENTh0310WANCHAI'

ss = iter(s)
if s.startswith('AD03A01'):
    list(islice(ss, 7))

row = []
while True:
    field_tag = ''.join(islice(ss, 2))
    if not field_tag:
        break
    field_length = int(''.join(islice(ss, 2)))
    field = ''.join(islice(ss, field_length))
    row.append(field)

formatted_line = ','.join(row)
```

This creates a generator for the string to iterate through using `islice`.  It reads the fixed length data (the field tag and the field length, then uses that to read the variable length data (the fields in the address).  When there is no more string left, it stops processing the string and formats them into a comma-delimited line.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):line 14, in <module>field_length = int(''.join(islice(ss, 2)))ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AD'

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I fixed a small bug with stripping off the beginning, but It's because your example isn't valid.  If you try this on real data where the *field length actually matches the field length value specified, it should work*

Comment: @sandeep Thanks, if you find an answer helpful, it's generally best practice to up vote it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: ya i tried doing that however as i dont have 15 reputation its not allowing me.

Comment: Brendan one more doubt and plz help me on the below.

Comment: TUEF1012345                                                                                                 AD03

Comment: TUEF1012345                                                                                          AD03A010105ABCDE0203ABC0310ABCDEFGHIJ

Comment: TUEF1012345                                                                                                          AD03A010105ABCDE0203ABC0310ABCDEFGHIJ                                                        AD03A020105ABCDE0203ABC0310ABCDEFGHIJ                                                                       AD03A030105ABCDE0203ABC0310ABCDEFGHIJ

Comment: @BrendanAbel Courtesy of a poorly worded question with a misleading and erroneous example!!! Down vote rescinded.

Comment: @Brendab need one more help in my above code if i dont have 2nd variable its going to 3rd field lenght however i need the 4 fields mandataorily.

Comment: for example ADDRESS2 is not der then i have to move spaces.

Comment: my valid field tags are 01,02,03,09

Comment: @Sandeep I don't really understand what you're asking. Either update your question or ask a new question with a clear explanation of your problem.

Comment: @Brendan in the above code we are not validating field_tag value hence if     my record is having 4 tags(01,02,03,09) then its writing those fields however if my record is having(01,02,09) tags then i have to move spaces  instead of moving tag09 value after tag02 value

Comment: @Sandeep It's trivial to test the value of `field_tag` and decide to include or exclude it from the row list.  I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out.